# Gerrit - plugin gerrit-owners-autoassign-1.1 install issue

Tags: java, plugins, gerrit

I am having the following Stacktrace:

> [2015-10-15 19:29:09,264] WARN 
>   com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Cannot load plugin
>   gerrit-owners-autoassign-1.1
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/gerrit/extensions/events/GitReferenceUpdatedListener$Update
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
>     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)    at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4830)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:533)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:160)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:123)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:233)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.ServerPlugin.startPlugin(ServerPlugin.java:190)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.ServerPlugin.start(ServerPlugin.java:170)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader.runPlugin(PluginLoader.java:461)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader.rescan(PluginLoader.java:390)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader.start(PluginLoader.java:295)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.lifecycle.LifecycleManager.start(LifecycleManager.java:74)
>     at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:293)  at
>   com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:205)     at
>   com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:64)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:166)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>   com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:50)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:25) Caused by:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/gerrit/extensions/events/GitReferenceUpdatedListener$Update
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
>     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)    at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4830)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:68)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:74)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
>     ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/gerrit/extensions/events/GitReferenceUpdatedListener$Update
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)   at
>   com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:688)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:93)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:37)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:45)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
>     ... 46 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.gerrit.extensions.events.GitReferenceUpdatedListener$Update
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 60 more

I am not really sure what I should look into to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instruction and ended up compiling the plugin with both changes submitted in here: https://github.com/vadims/gerrit-owners/issues/6 (look for the 2 forked repo) and it did work.

It was painful but the plugin does an awesome job so worth the effort!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a mismatch between the API version that the plugin was built against, and the API version of the Gerrit server.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gerrit/extensions/events/GitReferenceUpdatedListener$Update
```

The `GitReferenceUpdatedListener.Update` class was [removed from the API in Gerrit version 2.8](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/50778/).

To fix this you should first check which version of Gerrit your server is running, and then make sure you've built the plugin against the API with the corresponding version.

Comment: Yes i think i noticed what you just said last night, I need to make some edits and recompile the plugin to the proper version.

Comment: If that works, can you mark my answer as correct?  Thanks.

Comment: it was a step in the right direction but I ultimately add to look into another issue posted on the project and them recompile the current code with other modification to make it work. It was a bit of a painful process. So if anyone has the similar issue they should follow those instructions: https://github.com/vadims/gerrit-owners/issues/6 I will post an answer with it.!